# button does not display to both side of image slider

Tags: javascript, css, image, button, slider

im having trouble with css styling. I expect to have the button and the text number as this image [expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb7m3.png)(button is inside image and text is on top left), but my css show different[real](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OscfE.png). The area than contains the button is outside image, and I dont know how to set it inside image. The button is set to either left:0 and right: 0 to float to the edge of the image, but it did not display as expected. Bellow is html and css snippet

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    background-color: #eee;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card {
 display: none;
}
.card-container {
    margin: 50 auto auto auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}
.numbertext {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
img,iframe {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.text {
  text-align: center;
}

blockquote {
      display: block;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: -10px;
  }
 
img, iframe {
  /*filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);*/
}

/* Slideshow container */
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,.next{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  /*why it float*/
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}
.prev{
  margin-left: 0;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
 
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: -10px 2px 2px 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card-container">

        <div class="card">
               <div class="numbertext">1 / 7</div>
                 
                     <a href="https://youtu.be/gDmubAFyA2k"
                     target="_blank"><img src="p6.jpg"
                     style="width: 50%" title="click here to view song">
                 
               </a> 
           
             
   <div class="text">
       <!--speak up cannot embed video-->
       <h2>Speak up</h2>
   
   <blockquote>
       This song is played in one of the last scene when Edward saw Alice's vision and he saw Renesmee and Jacob together,
           it feels relieving.
   </blockquote>
   </div>
   </div>
   <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
   <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>     
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  </div>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please update the code so it can be run locally.

Comment: @RyanO'D Im not sure what u mean

Comment: Consider `img src="p6.jpg"` and `<script src="test.js"></script>`. Rather than linking to these assets with relative paths, you should update your code by providing an absolute link to an image and by including the actual JavaScript here. In this way, we can better run your code, analyze it, and offer feedback.